# Devise facebook login. @user not persisting, getting redirected to sign up page

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I followed all the instructions in Omniauth's walkthrough.

Note that my User model does not have name or image properties.

I followed the instructions in the Rails tutorial. However, I did have to change this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

to this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      # user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
      # user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

- an error was being thrown because User doesn't have `name` or `image` properties.
  That led to a new error:
  The @user created in the Omniauth_callbacks_controller is not persisting, so instead of getting signed-in, I'm just getting redirected back to the user sign-up page.

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    puts "BEFORE IF STATEMENT"
    puts @user.inspect
    if @user.persisted?
      puts "INSIDE IF STATEMENT"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      puts "AFTER ELSE STATEMENT"
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Server read out, which includes the `puts` statement and the @user object. You'll see that most of its fields are nil:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2015-09-01 20:41:01 +0100
I, [2015-09-01T20:41:01.891561 #7662]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for ::1 at 2015-09-01 20:41:01 +0100
I, [2015-09-01T20:41:01.978637 #7662]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQBcPU1SSS5908ZaCIgZjKnffSjG0PZTNcoyeSjiTbZDbVZvOKIz_YDoZzijNvfuc5QdIHczQPVAFqv3TMxDPZ_lGdUC3sg6d9iScaBgwVqU6uuoGppV7fAO-Q2ALN48is9-Exkr1o0JF2Yry9nebSxcSEDpBz39jDU0EMxOWCShGwG0CCaKLavOo0GzXzmZr1mpYaUZoBgxHSUdr3rRfhoqYMZOrYAYQeR8DMcAw7WR-C4PNKN9NyMwhzWDFv7mtoneP6dWAd22SNOLmQC64ahgJTFsN76brLl1Xl6HYR0wqjd4LBJeeV4uAumdVWkiIgo&state=0c40e8bcabffe59ec093223f78250db73c9a3d9b7717be97" for ::1 at 2015-09-01 20:41:02 +0100
I, [2015-09-01T20:41:02.098574 #7662]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"AQBcPU1SSS5908ZaCIgZjKnffSjG0PZTNcoyeSjiTbZDbVZvOKIz_YDoZzijNvfuc5QdIHczQPVAFqv3TMxDPZ_lGdUC3sg6d9iScaBgwVqU6uuoGppV7fAO-Q2ALN48is9-Exkr1o0JF2Yry9nebSxcSEDpBz39jDU0EMxOWCShGwG0CCaKLavOo0GzXzmZr1mpYaUZoBgxHSUdr3rRfhoqYMZOrYAYQeR8DMcAw7WR-C4PNKN9NyMwhzWDFv7mtoneP6dWAd22SNOLmQC64ahgJTFsN76brLl1Xl6HYR0wqjd4LBJeeV4uAumdVWkiIgo", "state"=>"0c40e8bcabffe59ec093223f78250db73c9a3d9b7717be97"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "10153518057141280"]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
BEFORE IF STATEMENT
#<User id: nil, email: nil, encrypted_password: "$2a$10$6Ls8Eng6pNFz11sV/AmOuuUdq8JRas33H8UnWAX0YyA...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, provider: "facebook", uid: "10153518057141280">
AFTER ELSE STATEMENT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 93ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/users/sign_up" for ::1 at 2015-09-01 20:41:02 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /Users/makerslaptop91/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /Users/makerslaptop91/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 55ms (Views: 54.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Notice the `puts` inside the 'if' statement was never printed.

routes.rb:

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  resources :restaurants do
    resources :reviews
  end

  root to: "restaurants#index"
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `:validatable` option then it will work.

Comment: I can not elaborate, unfortunately, as I do not know what the issue causing this is. 

I had a similar issue: the record did save the first time but when I deleted it and tried to sign up again it didn't save.